# QuerySet optimization

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to find a match between a serial number and a list of objects, each of them having a serial number :

models:

```
class Beacon(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='0')
```

First I wrote:

```
 for b in Beacon.objects.all():
      if b.serial == tmp_serial:
           # do something
           break
```

Then I did one step ahead:

```
b_queryset = Beacon.objects.all().filter(serial=tmp_serial)
     if b_queryset.exists():
         #do something
```

Now, is there a second step for more optimization?

I don't think it would be faster to cast my QuerySet in a List and do a list.index('tmp_serial').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your serial is unique, you can do:

```
# return a single instance from db
match = Beacon.objects.get(serial=tmp_serial)
```

If you have multiple objects to get with the same serial and plan do something on each of them, exist will add a useless query. 
Instead, you should do:

```
matches = Beacon.objects.filter(serial=tmp_serial)

if len(matches) > 0:
    for match in matches:
        # do something
```

The trick here is that `len(matches)` will force the evaluation of the queryset (so your db will be queried). After that, 
model instances are retrieved and you can use them without another query.

However, when you use `queryset.exists()`, the ORM run a really simple query to check if the queryset would have returned any element.
Then, if you iterate over your queryset, you run another query to grab your objects. See [the related documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) for more details.

To sum it up: use exists only if you want to check that a queryset return a result a result or not. If you actually need the queryset data, use `len()`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Do you think the exists() is super fast? Is it a good idea to first perform a exists() then get objects if exists() return True?

Comment: Exists is indeed super fast, but if you need the objects, get them directly, don't use exists. It will save you one query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are at best but if you just want whether object *exists* or not then,

From django queryset `exists()`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

```
 if Beacon.objects.all().filter(serial=tmp_serial).exists():
      # do something
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to get the object itself

Comment: Then you are doing best in this case. please accept the answer if you find it helping and solving your issue.

Comment: You can still move from two queries to a single one, see my answer